# number decomposition

Tags: code-golf, math, number, primes

It's been a while since I posted here, so here we go another day another challenge.

## Challenge :

Given a number(*`n`*) split it into it's prime factors.

---

## Input :

A positive non-zero integer greater than 2.

---

## Output :

Decompose the number into it's prime factors and return the number of occurances of each prime in it.

---

### Ouput format :

You can choose Any valid output format.

---

## Example :

```
n = 86240 
              v------------------------------- number of times it occurs in n 
output : [[2, 5], [5, 1], [7, 2], [11, 1]]
           ^-------------------------------- prime number

n = 7775460
                           v--------------- 5 only occurs once in 7775460 so we don't need to write any power 
output : [[2, 2], [3, 3], [5], [7], [11, 2], [17]]
            ^--------------------------------- same as first example
```

## Note :

- Prime factors have to be in either ascending order or descending order.
- You may choose to either write 1 as power or note

## Winning criterion :

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in bytes for each programming language wins

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

Built in command =)

```
ÆF
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wm9v///8tzIxMDAA)

---

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 10 bytes

```
ḋ≡ᵍ⟨h≡l⟩ᵐ
```

-1 bytes thanks to Erik the Outgolfer

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GO7kedCx9u7X00f0UGkJXzaP7Kh1sn/P9vYWZkYvA/CgA)